# load a div of a page by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a page using html, ajax and jQuery. In this page I have a div and a button. When I click the button, this button gets some data from another page, using jQuery and ajax, and load those in the div. That is correct. The problem is that when I type the url and open the page, the div form does show me nothing. Then when I click the button, the dic shows me the results.

What I am writing for is that I want to show the result in the div when I initialize the page. I mean, I type url and the page should show me the result in the div by default. Can you provide me any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `click` event handler in the button onto the `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the ajax thing using jQuery
`$(document).ready(function(){
    //Your ajax code here
});`
As soon as the DOM is ready i.e. completely loaded the ajax would be called and the answer would be shown as you want..
**Hopefully it helps.**